# Validating Telephone number not having all repeating digits

Tags: regex

I want to validate a telephone number of foramt (xxx) xxx-xxxx.
This number should not contain all repeating digits.
i.e, I have to validate if the user enters a number like (999) 999-9999. But should allow any other format.
How to write a regular expression for this.

Please help.

Thanks,
Siri

Comment: What regex flavor/tool are you using?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You show some code and we (maybe) try to fix it. We are not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Dont use a regex for this. If by chance you find one, who will maintain/understand/update it to have other restrictions in the future? Use code for the benefit of those that come after you.

Answer (score 0):

To validate a North American style phone number you could use:

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}-?\d{4}
```

This allows the repeating digits. To filter those out, you could run a second regex that uses [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to validate all the following digits match the first digit match. Here is a regex with phone formatting optional:

```
\(?(\d)\1\1\)?[- ]?\1{3}-?\1{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})
```

Prove here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iB1mW0/2)

Note that there has to be `\` between every bracket `()`. Otherwise they are interpreted as a capturing group.